# Graphics.Fillrectangle won't update

Tags: c#, graphics

I have the event-function that launches on click and in it i have a graphics instruction

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (modCLick)
        {
            case 2: 
                    session.g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Tomato, MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y, 50, 100);
                break;
        }
        ModCLick = 1;
    }
```

When i launch the program the click does nothing, but if I press a key (some keys only), the changes apply (I can see the rectangle). Why is not updating properly ? 
PS : don't worry about the case instruction.

Comment: Although I have been told not to worry, you know your switch variable and the last assignment are different objects? Don't know if this matters.

Comment: Almost, but i don't think that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing Graphics instances in global variables is a Very Bad Idea.  Make it look like this instead:

```
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image)) {
   g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Tomato, MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y, 50, 100);
   pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

The Invalidate() call is the one you are looking for.  PictureBox can only tell that you changed the Image property, it can't tell that you changed the image *content*.